# Simultaneous differential equations with no solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem as a part of a self taught course on calc I was doing

Leyt $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ satisfy the differential equations $$\frac{du}{dx}+ p(x)u= f(x) \tag1$$ and $$\frac{dv}{dx} + p(x)v=g(x) \tag 2$$ respectively where $p(x)$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous functions. If $u(x_1) > v(x_1)$ for some $x_1$ and $f(x) > g(x), \ \forall \ x > x_1$, prove that any point $(x, y)$, where $x>x_1$ does not satisfy the equation $y=u(x)$ and $y=v(x)$.

My approach:

We assume the contradictory that $ \exists \ x>x_1 $ such that $(x, y)$ satisfies $y=u(x)$ and $y=v(x)$ To avoid confusion I call this point $(h,k)$.

According to $ (1)$ and $(2)$, $$u'(h)-v'(h)=f(h)-g(h)$$

Which implies $$ u'(h) > v'(h) \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ h > x_1$$

But this would mean that the slope of $u$ must always be greater than slope of $v$ which cannot be true.

Comment: You assumed the existence of a *single* point $h > x_1$ with $u(h) = v(h)$. and derive $u'(h) > v'(h)$. But suddenly you claim this is true of *all* points $h > x_1$. How so? And even if it did hold for all $h >x_1$, why can it not be true that the slope of $u$ is always greater than the slope of $v$? It doesn't contradict anything you've said.